# Why SVG bbox method on Text element gives different result in different browser?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an SVG text element. I get its bbox in IE9, Chrome and Firefox and all three of them gives me different values.

I've create a really simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GhWTw/) that displays an SVG text and its size so you can see what I mean. I've also tried the client rect to see if it was any better.

**HTML/SVG**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="75px">
    <text font-size="8pt" id="text_name" x="30" y="44" fill="#000000" stroke-width="0pt" font-family="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" text-anchor="middle" visibility="inherit">
        <tspan x="30" y="44" dy="8">Text Content</tspan></text>
</svg> 
<div id="size"></div>
```

**Test javascript**

```
var bbox1 = document.getElementById("text_name").getBBox();
var f = document.getElementById("text_name").getClientRects();
document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = "<p>Width:" + bbox1.width + " Height: " + bbox1.height + "<br>" +  "Width:" + f[0].width +  " Height: " + f[0].height + "</p>";
```

As you can see, the font used is the common Arial, which is present in the three tested browsers and the font-size is also specified. I was therefore expecting the text to have the same bounds in all three browsers. I need to calculate the text bounds so I can export it and reuse it in another tool, so I need a values that are consistent.

If I can figure out why the values differ, I could make the proper adjustment to be sure the bounds will be suitable in all cases.

Here are the results of getBBox() in different browsers:

```
IE9 : Width:61.029998779296875 Height: 12.260002136230468
Chrome: Width:61 Height: 14
Firefox: Width:64.63671875 Height: 13
```

Comment: You can use the max value in three values.

Comment: @cuixiping You mean the higher bounds from all the three Browsers? The problem is that I don't have the other bounds to compare. My client use one browser which gives me a value that I must work with.

Comment: So 6 years later, Edge and Chrome now gives similar result and Firefox has different values.


Edge:Width:61.90625 Height: 12 

Chrome:Width:61.90625 Height: 12

Firefox: Width:63 Height: 12

Comment: You should not expect that firefox and chrome have absolutely same result. And also you should not expect that windows and mac have absolutely same result.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into setting the Viewport of your base SVG to obtain better results. View boxing might be needed to ensure the text element sizing is consistent results.  The linked article details these extremely well.

```
<svg height="14" width="61" ...
```

See [SVG Viewport and View Box](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html#viewbox)

Comment: I am afraid, this is not helpful. Melanie raised a question with respect to getting the size of text in different browsers. The settings of Viewport are the same in both. I still face the same issue and could not yet find a proper solution.

Comment: I even played around with box-sizing css property but no sucess